# Need Regular Expression (RegEx) to replace floating-point numbers in XML

Tags: xml, regex, vb.net

I'm using Visual Basic 2010 Express to edit an XML file. I want to replace items that have (typically) non-zero floating point numbers with a single zero.

Start with:

```
<Body RelArmLen="1.234" RelLegLen="-9.876" RelWaist="-3.14159">
```

End with:

```
<Body RelArmLen="1.234" RelLegLen="0" RelWaist="-3.14159">
```

The numbers may or may not start with - (minus) and may have any number of digits on either side of the decimal. If the starting value is zero to begin with, it may or may not have a decimal (that is, it might be "0" or "0.0" or "0.00"). None of the values have +; absence of - implies positive.

(My problem seems to be dealing with the quotes; I can get it to match everything from the RelLegLen=" to the last quote before >, or RelLegLen=" by itself, but not just the float between the quotes that belong to RelLegLen)

Thanks!

Comment: You should use an XML parser (XLINQ)

Comment: Remember: if you have a problem and you try to solve it using Regex, you now have problems... plural! -- Scott Hanselman in one of his many presentations.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Never use regular expressions to parse XML. Never. You'll get it wrong. For example, some of the proposed "solutions" will fail to match attributes that use single quote as a delimiter, but will "succeed" in matching quoted character strings that occur within text nodes.

This is an ideal candidate for XSLT, especially XSLT 2.0 which has regular expression support. Find the attributes you want to process with a template rule, then use the XPath 2.0 expression "castable as xs:double" to test if the format is floating point.

Comment: Thanks! This is probably best advice for the wider audience. The answer I originally accepted happens to work in my case, because the XML files I'm working with are a pretty predictable subset of the entire gamut of well-formed XML allowed (that is, even though single quote is allowed, I don't expect to ever see it in these particular XML files).

Comment: I would agree that 99% of the time you shouldn't use regex to parse XML, but I wouldn't say that you should *never* use it. The OP's comment above is a good example. If you have consistent data, it's a one time fix, and you can verify your modifications, go ahead and use regex.

Comment: Yes DevNull, I will definitely use your recommendation from time to time for my specific use case, and I really appreciate it.

Answer (score 1):

Couldn't you just do this:

```
RelLegLen="[^"]*"
```

It seems like you want to change anything that is in RelLegLen to 0.

Comment: Worked like a charm, satisfying my simple needs. Thanks!

Comment: You're very welcome. I usually suggest an XML parser like some of the other users have, but I also sometimes use this simple regex to replace attribute values. Usually in a text editor.

Comment: Yes, all I needed today was to jamb out this one file real quick. In the future when I have more time or justification, I'll look into the parsers.

Answer (score 1):

Why try and do this with Regex? .Net has a wonderful XML parser that can do the job for you. Look at this page for help on XML in VB: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb918016.aspx

Comment: You're probably right. I'm using RegEx bceause I thought this would be a simple straightforward text search-and-replace, and I might as well use tools I have on hand, rather than digging into something new. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Use non-greedy matching:

```
/RelLegLen="(.*?)"/
```

This will match from `/RelLegLen="` until the next `"`. The submatch will contain your float.

Comment: I got "Search text not found". May be weak implementation of RegEx in VB 2010 Express, or a typ-o on my part.

Answer (score 0):

Subject seems to be completed but maybe someone find it valuable, that is regex I used in VS2015 to look for hardcoded numbers in string and worked well:

```
\"[-+]?\d+(.\d+)?\"
```